# Linux Mint 20.2: 4k monitor with i915 (Intel Xe Graphics)

Tags: ubuntu, linux-mint, intel-graphics

**My laptop:**
ThinkPad Lenovo E14 Gen 2
Type Number: 20TA-000DGE
CPU: 11th Gen Intel i7-1165G7 (8) @ 4.700GHz (Rocket Lake)
GPU: Intel Device 9a49 / i915
Thunderbolt: v4 (only one; needed for power and external monitor)
HDMI

**My monitor:**
LG 27UK850/BK85U
4k (3840*2160)

**My external USB-C hub:** DockTeck (find with headline "USB C Hub, Dockteck 7-in-1 Dock HyperExtended USB C Ethernet Adapter, 4K 60Hz HDMI, LAN RJ45, 100W PD, 2 USB-3.0, SD/microSD, für MacBook Pro/Air, iPad Pro/Air/Mini 6, Surface Pro 7, XPS 13")

**Behavior on windows 10:** HDMI and the USB-c hub provide both a stable display on my monitor, with 4k and 60hz (hint: on windows, HDMI did only work @60hz after BIOS update).

**My problems:** on Linux I get these behaviors:

- Linux Mint 20.2, Kernel 5.11, HDMI: 4k @ 60hz, but: Ultra-HDMI is not working, so 1px lines show mostly the wrong color, font rendering does not draw correctly the transition to the background. Best seen in the terminal with colorful characters (see screenshot).
- Linux Mint 20.2, Kernel 5.11, USB-C hub: 4k @ 60hz; but: the 4k display flickers (1-2 second black screen; after some of these flushes the external monitor turns black)
- Linux Mint 20.2, Kernel 5.13 OEM (secure-boot activated), HDMI: 4k @ 30hz; 60hz is not available.
- Linux Mint 20.2, Kernel 5.13 OEM (secure-boot activated), USB-C hub: monitor does not wake up / no signal.
- Ubuntu 21.10, Kernel 5.1x, HDMI: 4k @ 30hz; 60hz is not available. I tried the new live-usb image, but also here: no better results on both interfaces. Sorry, on the live-usb I did not save any results.
- Ubuntu 21.10, Kernel 5.1x, USB-c hub: monitor does not wake up / no signal.

Some data from kernel 5.11:

```
sebl@sed14:~$ inxi -Fxz
System:
  Kernel: 5.11.0-34-generic x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: N/A 
  Desktop: Cinnamon 5.0.5 Distro: Linux Mint 20.2 Uma 
  base: Ubuntu 20.04 focal 
Machine:
  Type: Laptop System: LENOVO product: 20TA000DGE v: ThinkPad E14 Gen 2 
  serial: <filter> 
  Mobo: LENOVO model: 20TA000DGE v: SDK0J40697 WIN serial: <filter> 
  UEFI: LENOVO v: R1EET41W(1.41 ) date: 07/30/2021 
CPU:
  Topology: Quad Core model: 11th Gen Intel Core i7-1165G7 bits: 64 
  type: MT MCP arch: Tiger Lake rev: 1 L2 cache: 12.0 MiB 
  flags: avx avx2 lm nx pae sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3 vmx 
  bogomips: 44851 
  Speed: 716 MHz min/max: 400/4700 MHz Core speeds (MHz): 1: 826 2: 507 
  3: 1087 4: 766 5: 568 6: 581 7: 1045 8: 534 
Graphics:
  Device-1: Intel vendor: Lenovo driver: i915 v: kernel bus ID: 00:02.0 
  Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.11 driver: modesetting 
  unloaded: fbdev,vesa resolution: 1920x1080~60Hz, 3840x2160~60Hz 
  OpenGL: renderer: Mesa Intel Xe Graphics (TGL GT2) v: 4.6 Mesa 21.0.3 
  direct render: Yes 

sebl@sed14:~$ neofetch 
             ...-:::::-...                 sebl@sed14 
          .-MMMMMMMMMMMMMMM-.              ---------- 
      .-MMMM`..-:::::::-..`MMMM-.          OS: Linux Mint 20.2 x86_64 
    .:MMMM.:MMMMMMMMMMMMMMM:.MMMM:.        Host: 20TA000DGE ThinkPad E14 Gen 2 
   -MMM-M---MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM.MMM-       Kernel: 5.11.0-34-generic 
 `:MMM:MM`  :MMMM:....::-...-MMMM:MMM:`    Uptime: 42 mins 
 :MMM:MMM`  :MM:`  ``    ``  `:MMM:MMM:    Packages: 2136 (dpkg) 
.MMM.MMMM`  :MM.  -MM.  .MM-  `MMMM.MMM.   Shell: bash 5.0.17 
:MMM:MMMM`  :MM.  -MM-  .MM:  `MMMM-MMM:   Resolution: 1920x1080 
:MMM:MMMM`  :MM.  -MM-  .MM:  `MMMM:MMM:   DE: Cinnamon 
:MMM:MMMM`  :MM.  -MM-  .MM:  `MMMM-MMM:   WM: Mutter (Muffin) 
.MMM.MMMM`  :MM:--:MM:--:MM:  `MMMM.MMM.   WM Theme: Mint-Y-Dark (Mint-Y) 
 :MMM:MMM-  `-MMMMMMMMMMMM-`  -MMM-MMM:    Theme: Mint-Y [GTK2/3] 
  :MMM:MMM:`                `:MMM:MMM:     Icons: Mint-Y [GTK2/3] 
   .MMM.MMMM:--------------:MMMM.MMM.      Terminal: gnome-terminal 
     '-MMMM.-MMMMMMMMMMMMMMM-.MMMM-'       CPU: 11th Gen Intel i7-1165G7 (8) @ 4.700GHz 
       '.-MMMM``--:::::--``MMMM-.'         GPU: Intel Device 9a49 
            '-MMMMMMMMMMMMM-'              Memory: 4309MiB / 15710MiB 
               ``-:::::-``


sebl@sed14:~$ inxi -G 
Graphics:  Device-1: Intel driver: i915 v: kernel 
           Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.11 driver: modesetting unloaded: fbdev,vesa resolution: 1920x1080~60Hz 
           OpenGL: renderer: Mesa Intel Xe Graphics (TGL GT2) v: 4.6 Mesa 21.0.3 
sebl@sed14:~$ glxinfo -B
name of display: :0
display: :0  screen: 0
direct rendering: Yes
Extended renderer info (GLX_MESA_query_renderer):
    Vendor: Intel (0x8086)
    Device: Mesa Intel(R) Xe Graphics (TGL GT2) (0x9a49)
    Version: 21.0.3
    Accelerated: yes
    Video memory: 3072MB
    Unified memory: yes
    Preferred profile: core (0x1)
    Max core profile version: 4.6
    Max compat profile version: 4.6
    Max GLES1 profile version: 1.1
    Max GLES[23] profile version: 3.2
OpenGL vendor string: Intel
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa Intel(R) Xe Graphics (TGL GT2)
OpenGL core profile version string: 4.6 (Core Profile) Mesa 21.0.3
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 4.60
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile

OpenGL version string: 4.6 (Compatibility Profile) Mesa 21.0.3
OpenGL shading language version string: 4.60
OpenGL context flags: (none)
OpenGL profile mask: compatibility profile

OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.2 Mesa 21.0.3
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.20

sebl@sed14:~$ sudo lshw -c video
[sudo] Passwort für sebl:         
  *-display                 
       Beschreibung: VGA compatible controller
       Produkt: Intel Corporation
       Hersteller: Intel Corporation
       Physische ID: 2
       Bus-Informationen: pci@0000:00:02.0
       Logischer Name: /dev/fb0
       Version: 01
       Breite: 64 bits
       Takt: 33MHz
       Fähigkeiten: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom fb
       Konfiguration: depth=32 driver=i915 latency=0 mode=1920x1080 visual=truecolor xres=1920 yres=1080
       Ressourcen: iomemory:600-5ff iomemory:400-3ff irq:155 memory:601c000000-601cffffff memory:4000000000-401fffffff ioport:4000(Größe=64) memory:c0000-dffff memory:4100000000-4106ffffff memory:4020000000-40ffffffff
sebl@sed14:~$ dmesg | grep drm
[    0.964386] i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] VT-d active for gfx access
[    0.964390] fb0: switching to inteldrmfb from EFI VGA
[    0.965463] i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] Number of memory channels is zero
[    0.966536] i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] Finished loading DMC firmware i915/tgl_dmc_ver2_08.bin (v2.8)
[    1.091657] [drm] Initialized i915 1.6.0 20201103 for 0000:00:02.0 on minor 0
[    1.140991] fbcon: i915drmfb (fb0) is primary device
[    1.145355] i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] fb0: i915drmfb frame buffer device
[    5.604303] systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Load Kernel Module drm being skipped.
[  101.492264] i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] *ERROR* CPU pipe B FIFO underrun
```

Some data from kernel 5.13 OEM, linux mint 20.2

```
➜  ~ inxi -G 
Graphics:  Device-1: Intel driver: i915 v: kernel 
           Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.11 driver: modesetting unloaded: fbdev,vesa 
           resolution: 1920x1080~60Hz, 3840x2160~30Hz 
           OpenGL: renderer: Mesa Intel Xe Graphics (TGL GT2) 
           v: 4.6 Mesa 22.0.0-devel (git-f13d486 2021-11-03 focal-oibaf-ppa) 
➜  ~ 
➜  ~ 
➜  ~ inxi                                                                                 
CPU: Quad Core 11th Gen Intel Core i7-1165G7 (-MT MCP-) speed/min/max: 1055/400/4700 MHz 
Kernel: 5.13.0-1017-oem x86_64 Up: 1m Mem: 1281.1/15687.3 MiB (8.2%) Storage: 476.94 GiB (52.6% used) Procs: 278 
Shell: zsh 5.8 inxi: 3.0.38 
➜  ~ 
➜  ~ 
➜  ~ 
➜  ~ lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 VGA                                                           
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:9a49] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:5088]
    Kernel driver in use: i915
➜  ~
```

**My research:**

Yes, I updated BIOS.

The drivers are loaded, so [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1299067/ubuntu-20-04-no-driver-loaded-for-intel-iris-xe-graphics) is not my problem.

I tried the OEM kernel, as suggested [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1303586/1517175), but without resolution. See terminal output.

Regarding the "[drm] *ERROR* CPU pipe B FIFO underrun" I did find several threads regarding the boot options for c-states.
I tried lowering the power-savings (c-states) as suggested in [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1272268/ubuntu-20-04-continious-screen-flicker-after-return-from-supend-error-cpu) and described in the [arch-wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/intel_graphics#X_freeze/crash_with_intel_driver). No improvement.

I installed the drivers from [the ppa of oibaf](https://launchpad.net/%7Eoibaf/+archive/ubuntu/graphics-drivers) as suggested [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1309561/ubuntu-20-10-how-to-use-iris-driver-with-intel-iris-xe-graphics). No improvement (caution: "Revert to original drivers" with ppa-purge did not work for me) for any kernel.

I can disable the "HDMI Ultra HD Deep Color" at the menu of my monitor; then Linux switches to 30hz with a rude drawing of the pixels.

Sadly I can not try kernel 5.14 with my Linux Mint, as some lib for c-compiling is not available in the proper version (I just forgot the name).

Screenshot for Linux Mint 20.2, Kernel 5.11, HDMI: 4k @ 60hz:
[image: Normal view, taken with my mobile]
[image: view with a lens, taken with my mobile]
What you can see in the picture:

- red "N/A": You see big "steps" in the diagonal lines.
- green "v14.17.5" (also at the yellow text): at the bottom pixels, the transition is painted with white (between green and black)
- to be clear: this does only affect the external monitor with 4k: When I move the window to the internal screen (HD resolution) it looks fine.

*Thanks for reading! Any questions for details are welcome. :-)
In my opinion, 4k on that machine is not yet running anywhere on a standard Ubuntu system. Hopefully, we get this popular hardware running, as good as windows. ;-)*

Comment: Today I tried the linux kernel OEM 5.14: 

With HDMI (laptop) to HDMI (monitor) the same visual result as in the screenshots (these big red "steps" on diagonal pixel edges).
And with HDMI (on the USB-C hub) to HDMI (monitor) or with USB-C (laptop) out to DP (monitor) or with USB-C (laptop) to USB-C (monitor): In all of these setups (with USB-C involved) the screen has a nice, sharp font rendering, but the flickering happens again and makes it totally unusable.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same Issues than you. Try using Display port, that fixed it for me.
You HDMI version ist just 1.4b (https://www.hdmi.org/spec/hdmi1_4b). This version doesn't support 4k@60Hz.

There are many HDMI to Displayport adapters out there.

Comment: Why would a HDMI to Displayport adapters help?

Comment: Because your Displayport version officially supports 4k@60Hz. I have the same Hardware (And nearly same monitor as you, also LG 4k) and it worked for me. You could also try a USB-C to Displayport Adapter

Comment: I also tried a USB-C to USB-C cable. The video signal comes with 4k@60hz but again with the flickering (which makes it unusable). The flickering occurs mostly when windows are moved or updated (with a web browser it happens always); an empty desktop with no open windows and only the mouse pointer is moved would not flicker.

Comment: Yup, I am having the same issue. What I could find out: It works in [swaywm](https://swaywm.org/), maby Xfce but other major Desktops/WM's don't work (like plasma, gnome, dwm, awesomewm, bspwm, etc.) I've reported this bug on kde plasma. It would be great if you could also comment that you are having the same issue: https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=448177#add_comment